# Не отображается картинка фоном Background

Tags: html, css, background

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Golden Tage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">

    </div>
    </header>
<footer>
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

в CSS (Sublime text 3)

```
.header { background: url(../img/back.jpg) no-repeat center / top cover;
height: 600px
 }
```

http://prntscr.com/hygvbh - Расположение файлов

Comment: <header class="header">

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Comment: У Вас скорее всего либо с классом header что-то напутано, либо просто относительная ссылка неверно указана - см.подробнее здесь - http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в таком вот синтаксисе - "center / top cover". Если Вы уверены, что добавили хедеру класс header и путь к картинке указали верный, то запишите css-правила так:

```
.header {
  height: 600px;
  background: url('../img/back.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если уж вы решили писать одним большим свойством, то правильно будет

```
.header {
  background: url(../img/back.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
}
```

Но лучше разнесите это по разным свойствам, как минимум `background-size`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

1. Ошибка в CSS, а именно прописан класс `.header`, а нужно `header`, без точки.
2. Ошибка в свойствах:

   `header {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url('../img/back.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    }`
3. Не верно указана ссылка на картинку. `('../img/back.jpg')`, возможно формат картинки не `.jpg`, а `.jpeg` или же `.png`.

Comment: Спасибо первый пункт помог вкупе с верхним комментом